# Using I2C/SMBus with Sense HAT and Output stays the same

Tags: python, i2c, sensor, sense-hat

I have a problem while reading the my lsm9ds1 acceleratorsensor registers . It always displays the same values.

My setup is a raspberry pi 4 and the sense HAT which has this sensor integrated. I dont want to use the sense hat library but use the python3-smbus library to better understand I2C.

The registers i want to read from are OUT_X_XL, OUT_Y_XL and OUT_Z_XL which return linear values expressed as a 16-bit word in two's complement. [Here is the Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm9ds1.pdf). I tried to convert them with two different functions i found, but got both times an error so i just wanted to see if there just would be a change if i move the sensor around.

Here is my output:

```
Complements Register 1 X: 221 Y: 59  Z: 254
Complements Register 2 X: 104 Y: 146  Z: 112
Complements Register 1 X: 221 Y: 59  Z: 254
Complements Register 2 X: 104 Y: 146  Z: 112
```

Do i have to do something different with the values or should i read the register differently? Preferably i would also like the values to be something close to float values what you would expect from an acceleration sensor. Any help is very appreciated

Here is my code:

```
from smbus import SMBus
import time

i2c_adress = 0x1c # DEVICE ACCELEROMETER

#DEFINITION OF REGISTERS
OUT_X_XL1 = 0x28   # linear acceleration sensor output registers
OUT_X_XL2 = 0x29
OUT_Y_XL1 = 0x2A
OUT_Y_XL2 = 0x2B
OUT_Z_XL1 = 0x2C 
OUT_Z_XL2 = 0x2D



def main():
    i2cbus = SMBus(1) # Create new I2C bus
    
    
    while (True):
        comp_acc_x2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_X_XL2)
        comp_acc_y2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Y_XL2)
        comp_acc_z2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Z_XL2)
        
        comp_acc_x1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_X_XL1)
        comp_acc_y1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Y_XL1)
        comp_acc_z1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Z_XL1)
        
        print(f" Complements Register 1 X: {comp_acc_x1} Y: {comp_acc_y1}  Z: {comp_acc_z1}")
        print(f" Complements Register 2 X: {comp_acc_x2} Y: {comp_acc_y2}  Z: {comp_acc_z2}")
        
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

New Code using pigpio:

```
import pigpio
import time

i2c_adress = 0x1c # DEVICE ACCELEROMETER

#DEFINITION OF REGISTERS
OUT_X_XL1 = 0x28   # linear acceleration sensor output registers
OUT_X_XL2 = 0x29
OUT_Y_XL1 = 0x2A
OUT_Y_XL2 = 0x2B
OUT_Z_XL1 = 0x2C
OUT_Z_XL2 = 0x2D

def main():
    pi = pigpio.pi()
    acc_sensor = pi.i2c_open(1, i2c_adress)
    
    
    while(True):
        pi.i2c_write_device(acc_sensor, OUT_X_XL1)
        comp_acc_x1 = pi.i2c_read_device(acc_sensor, OUT_X_XL1)
        print(f" Complements Register 1 X: {comp_acc_x1} ")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

New Error Message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/home/.../mix/pigpio_sense_hat.py", line 52, in <module>
        main()   
File "/home/.../mix/pigpio_sense_hat.py", line 36, in main
        pi.i2c_write_device(acc_sensor, OUT_X_XL1)   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 3185, in i2c_write_device
        if len(data): TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: The sensehat library presumably uses the smbus library.  Why not see how the sensehat library uses smbus?

Comment: That was a good idea @joan sadly i am not very good at reading all this code with no comments. I found some i2c snippets but no clear indication how they communicate. If you want to try your luck, [here ist the link] (https://github.com/RPi-Distro/RTIMULib/tree/master/Linux)

Comment: i just tried to use the pigpio library and i ran into the same problem.

Comment: If you use pigpio use i2c_write_device(handle, 0x28) then i2c_read_device(handle, 6) to read all 6 bytes at once.

Comment: @joan why would i use i2c_write_device()? Honest question, because i never used that library, but it just makes sense to use i2c_read_byte or however its called

Comment: The I2C commands are simpler and more flexible than the smbus commands.  Read/write device are I2C commands.  The others are smbus commands.  In this case the write is used to set the register you want to read from.

Comment: @joan i tried your suggestion but i got an error. I will edit my post with the error and the new code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137480/discussion-between-xenoshell-and-joan).

Comment: @joan i found a solution, do you know how i could calculate the output so its more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how, but the solution was very simple. Here is the while loop for both libraries.

Pigpio:

```
while(True):
        comp_acc_x2 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_X_XL2)
        comp_acc_y2 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_Y_XL2)
        comp_acc_z2 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_Z_XL2)
        
        comp_acc_x1 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_X_XL1)
        comp_acc_y1 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_Y_XL1)
        comp_acc_z1 = pi.i2c_read_byte_data(acc_sensor, OUT_Z_XL1)
        
        print(f" Complements Register 1 X: {comp_acc_x1} Y: {comp_acc_y1}  Z: {comp_acc_z1}")
        print(f" Complements Register 2 X: {comp_acc_x2} Y: {comp_acc_y2}  Z: {comp_acc_z2}") 
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

SMBus (here i just had to put the SMBus object into the loop):

```
while (True):
        i2cbus = SMBus(1) # Create new I2C bus
        comp_acc_x2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_X_XL2)
        comp_acc_y2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Y_XL2)
        comp_acc_z2 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Z_XL2)
        
        comp_acc_x1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_X_XL1)
        comp_acc_y1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Y_XL1)
        comp_acc_z1 = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2c_adress, OUT_Z_XL1)

        print(f" Complements Register 1 X: {comp_acc_x1} Y: {comp_acc_y1}  Z: {comp_acc_z1}")
        print(f" Complements Register 2 X: {comp_acc_x2} Y: {comp_acc_y2}  Z: {comp_acc_z2}")
        
        time.sleep(1.5)
```